# Time and Space complexity of BFS and DFS, on Graph in AdjacencyMatrix and AdjacencyList

Tags: time, graph, complexity-theory, space, breadth-first-search

i have performed BFS and DFS ( For printing the Graphs) --> with multiple Implementations.
But I am confused with the time complexity of them, while reading online some say its O(V^2) . some say its O(|V+E|)
i am  really confused now.

I am attaching my different implementations . [Attaching as Link for better Syntax highlighting]
1. [Graph_AdjMat --> graph with matrix implementation](https://ide.codingblocks.com/s/74184)

2. [Graph_AdjList --> graph with list< list> implementation](https://ide.codingblocks.com/s/74185)
3. [Graph_AdjList_Weighted_Map   graph for weighted scenario, weights imipllements using Map, to map node -> node_weight](https://ide.codingblocks.com/s/74186)
4. [Graph_AdjList_Weighted_Vertex   graph for weighted scenario, weights imipllements using Vertex class](https://ide.codingblocks.com/s/74187)

Mainly you need to check the  code  (1)  (2) & (3)

```
as in code (1) : implementation using matrix.       [[[ CONSTANT time  for checking if two node's are connected ]]]
in code(2) . : implementation using List of Lists     [[[ --> here it takes O(N) for checking if two node's are connected ]]]
in code(3) . : implementation using List of Maps     [[[ --> CONSTANT time  for checking if two node's are connected ]]]
```

So if i  implement dfs & bfs in all of them, What will be the Time and Space complexity of the DFS and BFS?

```
               TIME (DFS)         TIME (BFS)      SPACE (DFS)     SPACE (BFS)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Code 1  :   |                  |                  |             |              |
------------|------------------|------------------|-------------|--------------|
Code 2  :   |                  |                  |             |              |
------------|------------------|------------------|-------------|--------------|
Code 3  :   |                  |                  |             |              |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```